# convert PCRE regular expression to mysql query regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have below regular expression

```
^(?!\d+$)(?!(?:[^$&%@]*[$&%@]){4})(?!.*\b\w{11}).{3,}$
```

it is working fine in PHP

I want that converted to MySQL supported query. when I run above regular expression. I got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from reg-exp

please help to solve this

Comment: Something like `WHERE col REGEXP '^.{3,}$' AND col NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND col NOT REGEXP '([^$&%@]*[$&%@]){4}' AND col NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]][[:alnum:]_]{11}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not support lookarounds, nor does it support `\d` or `\w` classes. You may split the regex like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col REGEXP '^.{3,}$' AND col NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND col NOT REGEXP '([^$&%@]*[$&%@]){4}' AND col NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]][[:alnum:]_]{11}'
```

Where:

- `REGEXP '^.{3,}$'` - the total length should be 3 or more characters
- `AND col NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'` - string cannot consist of digits only
- `AND col NOT REGEXP '([^$&%@]*[$&%@]){4}'` - string cannot have 4 special chars
- `AND col NOT REGEXP '[[:alnum:]_]{11}'` - string cannot have a word with 11 chars

Comment: you are the best. i recommended you

Comment: @wiktor Stribizew Can you please help me to convert below Regex into MySql compatible? 
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})61(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[4]\d{8}$
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The work around is to use preg-like MySQL UDF Library that has more complex REGEXP than the native MySQL's own.

[https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme)

and you can type the above in the link below to get Perl version of the expression that will work directly with the udf

https://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/22/codegen?language=javascript